# The set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

Tags: general-topology

**Problem: The set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.**

This is what my prof posted before this problem.

While the following theorem does not depend on the topology one places on R, topology can be used to prove it. The more interesting question is "Must topology be used to prove it?"

I was trying to find a way to show this using topology and without using Cantors diagonalization and Dedekind cuts. Can there be a way to show that they are not countable? I am thinking and trying to come up with one for this. If I get it, I will type it and share.

Meanwhile, it will be great help if someone can suggest me what to do for this problem.

Comment: Without Dedekind cuts.  What's your definition of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is a set of all real numbers.

Comment: If you want to prove something about the real numbers then you need rather more detail in your definition than that.  Dedekind cuts are one way, but not the only way, to define them.

Answer (score 2):

If you define $\Bbb R$ via Cauchy sequences rather than Dedekind, as is done [here](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.095/2015IAP/lecture1/padic.pdf), for instance, you have immediately that $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric is a complete metric space. You can then apply the [Baire Category Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) for complete metric spaces, which says that if $\mathscr{D}$ is a countable family of dense open subsets of $\Bbb R$, then $\bigcap\mathscr{D}$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ (and in particular is non-empty).

Now for each $x\in\Bbb R$ let $D_x=\Bbb R\setminus\{x\}$, and consider $\bigcap_{x\in\Bbb R}D_x$.